# why does the shortcut for "image.open" not work ? (ALT + O)

Tags: workflow

i use this "open image" button a lot , so i decided to use a shortcut for it on my MacBook Pro.
 i put my mouse on the link to see the python code. "image.open"
 i searched it up in the prefs.
there it says the shortcut is:  ALT + O  .
i tried it , but it is not working. 
i changed the shortcut into: shift + O  .
 that didn't work either.
 what am i missing here ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that shortcut doesn't work because it is under **UV/Image editor** shortcuts you have to add the same shortcut under the **Property editor** :

- go to User preferences->Input->Properties editor
- add the shortcut

[image]